# How to remove space reserved for \author in documentclass article's \maketitle?

Tags: pdftex, titles, article, author, date

The space reserved for `\date` is removed when it is left empty. Compare the two examples below.

1.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\title{Test}
\author{Dave}
\date{Tomorrow}
\maketitle

This is a test.
\end{document}
```

2. 

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\title{Test}
\author{Dave}
\date{}
\maketitle

This is a test.
\end{document}
```

However the same does not hold for `\author`.

1.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\title{Test}
\author{Dave}
\date{Tomorrow}
\maketitle

This is a test.
\end{document}
```

2. 

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\title{Test}
\author{}
\date{Tomorrow}
\maketitle

This is a test.
\end{document}
```

Contrary to the previous example, miniscule amount of space is saved. How can I make it so that there is no redundant space between `\title` and `\date` when `\author` is omitted?